# The X and Y coordinates of the right callout button are not placing my views accurately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

As you can see below I am using the calloutaccessorycontrol's coordinates to place another view on my mapview. However. it never seems to place the control anywhere near the calloutaccessorycontrol. This is strange, because I am using its x and y coordinates.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
                      calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    HotelInformationViewController *vc = 
    [[HotelInformationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HotelInformationViewController" 
    bundle:nil control:control];

    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil control:(UIControl *)control
{
  if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) 
  {
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(control.frame.origin.x, control.frame.origin.y, 286, 286); //As you can see here I am using the x and y to place the new control
  }
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the frame instead of the bounds.

But the other problem is that the callout button's position is relative to the popup view of the annotation (not self.view).  The annotation's popup position is relative to the map view, etc.

You need to convert the callout's position to the self.view's coordinate system using the `convertPoint:toView:` method.

Modify the init method as follows:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
              control:(UIControl *)control 
           withParent:(UIView *)parentView
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) 
    {
        CGPoint calloutOriginInParent = 
            [control convertPoint:control.bounds.origin toView:parentView];

        CGRect myFrame;
        myFrame.origin.x = 
            calloutOriginInParent.x + control.frame.size.width + 5;
        myFrame.origin.y = calloutOriginInParent.y;
        myFrame.size.width = 286;
        myFrame.size.height = 286;
        self.view.frame = myFrame;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In the init method above, you'll also have to adjust the hotel view's frame so that it doesn't show up off screen which could happen if the callout is near the right or bottom edge of the screen.

Then in the calloutAccessoryControlTapped method:

```
HotelInformationViewController *vc = [[HotelInformationViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"HotelInformationViewController" 
    bundle:nil 
    control:control 
    withParent:self.view];

[self.view addSubview:vc.view];

[vc release];
```